# Getter for Windows handles

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, clion

So I've been learning C++ for several months now, and I ran into a weird occurrence with my IDE. (Jetbrains CLion FTW!)

My IDE can generate getters for members, automatically determining the type, const or not, and other keywords. Obviously the generation is not perfect, so I find myself usually not using this feature. So at the moment I'm focusing on the Windows API, which requires working with handles. So something really weird happens when I generate a getter to a handle (HINSTANCE, HWND, HDC, etc...).

Say I have a member defined as follows:

```
HDC m_hDeviceContext;
```

Then when my IDE generates a getter it looks something like this:

```
const HDC__* getDeviceContext() const...
```

I'm so confused to why the type is HDC__. It makes sense that it is a pointer, hence a handle is declared as a pointer (typedef struct name##__ *name) in winnt.h.

Could anyone give me some insight on why this is occurring? Is it a bug with my IDE, because whenever I see examples of getters that return a handle, they usually just return straight that handle type.

Comment: It looks like a bug with your IDE. Or maybe a setting somewhere. Or at the very least a design flaw (if it's not a setting).

Comment: You're probably right, CLion is pretty new. What should it be generating?

Comment: I'd expect it to generate `HDC getDeviceContext() const {return m_hDeviceContext;}`, of course.

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HDC` is defined as a `typedef` for an opaque `struct` pointer:

```
typedef const struct HDC__ *HDC;
```

or in older windows version as a dummy type expanded from `DECLARE_HANDLE(HDC)`:

```
typedef struct HDC__{int i;}*HDC;
```

The purpose if this definition is to prevent confusion between different types of handles that would all be just integers if `typedef`ed as `WORD` or `LONG`, or `DWORD`.  Making them pointers to different structures prevents compilation in case of mismatches. Microsoft has been doing this for at least 20 years.

Your IDE probably looks at the debugging information instead of parsing the header files, and it does not reverse the effect of the `typedef`.

In C++, `struct` tags are implicitly `typedef`ed in the current namespace.  So `struct HDC__` also creates the type `HDC__`.  For some reason your IDE assumes that.  If you are compiling as C++, it should not be a problem.  If you were compiling as C, too bad, this bug would probably be the least of your problems.

Comment: I don't think it's looking at debugging information, probably it's just expanding the typedef.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: expanding the typedef from the `<winnt.h>` source requires a lot of work, close to a full grammatical C or C++ parser, not to mention non standard MS extensions.  I would be surprised if they did that.  It is much easier to compile the source on the fly and parse the debugging information.  The truth is none of this is needed: the member definition is all that's needed to produce the wrapper in this case.

Comment: I'm curious why did they define this structure though. Pointer to an incomplete type is a more strict entity. You can't even add zero to such pointer.

Comment: @MinorThreat: this extra level of type safety is exactly the purpose. Defining HDC and HWND as pointer to different opaque types prevents a programmer from passing an HWND where an HDC is expected, etc.

Comment: You cannot implicitly convert from one pointer ti incomplete type to another, either. Say, DHC__* cannot be converted to HBRUSH__* if HDC__ and HBRUSH__ are incomplete types.

Comment: @MinorThreat: That's exactly what I wrote.  A long time ago, handles were just defined as `typedef`s for `WORD`.  It was easy to get confused, passing the wrong kind of handle went undetected by the compiler.  These opaque struct typedefs are a big improvement to avoid silly mistakes.

Comment: No, the `typedef` for a WORD is not an incomplete type. Incomplete type is, for instance, a struct which is forward declared, but not defined. You can have a pointer to such `struct`, but you can't do anything with it except storing it in a variable or passing it to an external API.You can't even add literal zero to such pointer . This is an ideal solution for handles. But HDC__ isn't an incomplete type. It is a complete `struct` type without any members. Maybe Microsoft overlooked this possibility, i dunno. Or I'm talking about older `<windows.h>`. Haven't  take a look for a while.

Comment: @MinorThreat: You are correct, HDC is not an incomplete type, it is a dummy type defined by `DECLARE_HANDLE(HDC)`, which expands in `STRICT` mode as `typedef struct HDC__{int i;}*HDC`. I don't know why Microsoft decided to use a dummy struct in place of an incomplete type, maybe *Hanlon's Razor*.